# Check points in Developer Console to see variables values

Tags: developer-console, debugging, object

Instead of using System.debug() to see the variables values, Is possible to set checkpoints in developer console?? I have done that like this:

line 34 (Checkpoint) Integer i = 5;

Then I click the label checkpoints but I am not able to see anywhere, the value of my variable. Is possible to see anywhere something like:

i = 5

Is that possible?

Comment: Once a checkpoint location is set in the Edit properties you can specify the information you would like to collect and have an option to dump heap - which give you values of variable. Make sure that the Checkpoint is reached during the execution of debug .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that the checkpoint location is set correctly - if it is, it should appear under the 'checkpoint locations' section within the checkpoints tab.

Make sure you've got debug level set up correctly -

> IMPORTANT To set checkpoints, you need the View All Data user permission. To generate results using checkpoints, run code using execute anonymous, or set a DEVELOPER_LOG trace flag on yourself. The trace flag must have a log level for Apex of INFO or higher

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5

Then, **run the code** in question - and the variable details should appear in the checkpoints section (within the checkpoints tab).

If that doesn't work, try restart dev console, log in-out, etc. etc.